# Restore Purchases is Mandatory In case saved in our system?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, in-app-purchase, swift4.2

I searched a lot and did not find a concept for "In-App Purchases restore"

in our application all users can't used without login by email and pass, and all purchases saved in our system to enable multiple platform so the button of restore purchases is mandatory with this case or not?

Comment: Restore purchases is a good idea; it can be helpful when the purchase process fails somehow before your server has been updated

Answer (score 0):

The [App Store Review Guidelines says](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase):

> Any credits or in-game currencies purchased via in-app purchase may not expire, and you should make sure you have a restore mechanism for any restorable in-app purchases.

So yes, a restore mechanism is mandatory.

Apple of course doesn't say it needs to be a button. Perhaps you can implement it without any user input; for example at first app startup.

Also, a restore method is mandatory, regardless of where/if you store a purchase. I mean, if you wouldn't have a backend system, you are still required to have a restore mechanism.

(It's good to read all App Store Review Guidelines.)